# "error: cannot find symbol" using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi, classpath, xssf

This is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Reader {

    public static void read_excel() {

        File excel =  new File ("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-Tools\\data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
}
```

This results in the following error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol 
File excel =  new File ("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-Tools\\data.xlsx");
symbol: class File
location: class reader
```

I have set the CLASSPATH for the jar files of the Apache POI library. Here is the content of the CLASSPATH varibale:

```
.;C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Code\Classes;C:\poi-3.12\poi-3.12-20150511.jar;C:\poi-3.12\poi-ooxml-3.12-20150511.jar;C:\poi-3.12\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511.jar;C:\poi-3.12\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;C:\poi-3.12\lib\commons-codec-1.9.jar;C:\poi-3.12\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\poi-3.12\lib\junit-4.12.jar; C:\poi-3.12\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\poi-3.12\poi-examples-3.12-20150511.jar;C:\poi-3.12\poi-excelant-3.12-20150511.jar;C:\poi-3.12\poi-scratchpad-3.12-20150511.jar
```

I don't understand why the programme does not compile !

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean.  It explains the various reasons you can get a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error ... and why your program doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Add import statement for File

```
import java.io.File;
```

Comment: Thank you very much fpr your quick answer. I did as you told me and compiled the file again ... now I get the following error message:
"error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
          FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
          XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
2 errors"

Comment: Add try catchBlock and handle FileNotFoundException or add throws declaration to you method signature.                                                                      I would suggest you to use some IDEs in case you're not using any.

Comment: but why is the file not found ? ... the path to the file is correect.

Comment: You are still not getting any exception, its a compile time exception wherein you will need to handle any checked exception using try catch or throws keyword. For further info please read java api docs.

Comment: Compile time ERROR ... not exception.  (Please lets not confuse the beginner even further by using incorrect terminology.)

Answer (score 1):

try with the following code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class Reader {

    public static void read_excel() throws FileNotFoundException {

        File excel =  new File ("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-Tools\\data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ... with your code I get the following error message: 
"error: cannot find symbol   public static void read_excel() throws FileNotFoundException {
symbol: class FileNotFoundException
location: class Reader
1 error"

Comment: @steady_progress did you copy exactly all my code if yes then you need to add }

Comment: The [Apache POI docs are pretty clear](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream) on not using an `InputStream` if you have a `File`!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this code here finally did not produce an error message:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;





public class Reader {

    public static void read_excel()  throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File excel =  new File ("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\java-Tools\\data.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
}
```

Comment: If you have a `File`, use that, don't go via an `InputStream`! [The Apache POI docs explain why](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)!